# Sanitizing/validating user supplied values in php

Tags: php, validation

I have a function called `InputFilter` that I use for validating/sanitizing form data and I want to know how to implement it correctly into this? I need to run it through `$_GET['media']`. The file that the function `InputFilter` is in is `clean.php` and if I try to include `clean.php` into this it makes my result pages not show when a search is performed. This script below is my `search.php`. Even when I paste the contents of `clean.php` into `search.php` it will make my result pages blank and I am not sure why. Is there any easy way to get this to work or a simple way to sanitize/validate `$_GET['media']`?

```
$media = isset($_GET['media']) ? $_GET['media'] : 'no_media';
switch($media) {
 case 'all':
  include("all_media.php");
  break;
 case 'only':
  include("only_media.php");
  break;
 default:
  include("def_search.php");
}
```

I am open to any other way of securing `$_GET['media']`.

Comment: You might have to show your `clean.php`. Sounds like there is a syntax error which halts all further execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switch makes your script very save! No matter what anybody sets as media, there will be no security hole in this code.

To sanitize `$_GET` check the PHP method [`filter_input()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php).

Comment: Well if thats the case then I should be good. I ran a sql injection/xss attack software on my site and it told me media is vulnerable.

Comment: you are completely positive that the way my script is that it is fine? I just want to make sure it's safe so I can quit worrying.

Comment: Since there is NO way of inculde something else than one of this 3 scripts. You could add `unset($media);` after the switch, but this is not required.

Comment: You seem to be correct. I just googled some stuff and I have seen other people say similar. So thank you.